# How to scale (flip) in the center pixi.js

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm looking to flip a DisplayObjectContainer in Pixi.js, from the center. I figured out that scaling to -1 works for the flip but I can't get it to do so from the center, like you can with using anchor for Sprites. I also found this [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/webgl_transforms/) that explains what I'm trying to do in terms of WebGL, but of course I am trying to do this on a higher level with Pixi. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a few options, keeping it high-level. Hopefully one is suitable for your particular situation.

1: Flip the container and then offset the position:

```
container.scale.x *= -1;
container.position.x = centerX - container.scale.x * containerWidth / 2;
```

See this working example: http://codepen.io/ianmcgregor/pen/BmbHe

2: Center the content inside the DisplayObjectContainer:

```
var content = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
content.position.x = 0 - content.width / 2;
container.addChild(content);

container.scale.x *= -1;
```

3: Use a Sprite in place of DisplayObjectContainer. The drawback of this approach is that it will need to have a texture.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm trying #3 and I'm still having problems with anchoring. I'm setting the anchor as a PIXI.Point(0.5, 0.5) and it's sticking but the parent Sprite still is not scaling from the center. Any ideas?

Comment: I adjusted the codepen [link](http://codepen.io/ianmcgregor/pen/LJqHI). Realised the big drawback of using a sprite is it has to have some texture. How does yours differ from that new code?

Comment: Thank you so much! I realized that my parent Sprite's children were not inside. I forgot the transparency setting for my renderer was set to true, therefore I wasn't able to see things clearly. My project is a bit complicated. Thanks so much again. I'm sticking with #3 of your answer.